Where to caulk new window capping
I recently had new vinyl siding installed and it included new aluminum capping around the windows.  The capping was done after all siding was installed so the capping does not go behind the j channels, just up to the new foam board (except for drip caps above the windows/below j channel).  The installer did not caulk anything.  I mentioned it and he came back and caulked some windows in some spots, but nothing was consistent from one to another.  My windows were not replaced at this time, but have been previously.  Looking at some neighbors windows it appears all their windows are caulked on all 4 sides between the windows and capping and also between capping and j channels.  Should I caulk all 4 sides at both the inside and outside of capping?  If it makes a difference, about half the windows have drip caps between the capping and j channel, half don't because those have roof overhangs not far away.



Caulk has no business in a properly flashed vinyl siding installation. Vinyl siding moves too much for that to be effective. It results in false confidence in your water management strategy. (It also looks terrible on what's supposed to be a maintenance-free situation.) I would insist that the flashing be done properly.

I added 2 photos.  I don't believe anything was reflashed, just recapped trim.  Original house wrap was reused, they replaced foam board.

What you're calling "capping" is the flashing. Its flanges should've extended up behind the siding (it should've been done first). Any siding installer should've known this. It comes down to whether they care or not.
